# Howto use cli tools installed by pip under windows

Tags: python, pip

I have installed python 3.5.2 under windows. Now I can install [jinja2-cli](https://github.com/mattrobenolt/jinja2-cli) using

```
pip install jinja2-cli
```

If I would be under fedora/ubuntu, I could now call jinja2-cli from the terminal. But under windows this does not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: add the folder where it is installed to your PATH

Comment: I think they're located in the `Scripts` sub-directory of the python installation.